# Assigned Value to a Counter by Another, Prevents Counter from Incrementing?

Tags: c, loops, indexing

So here's my simple C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int i, j, k;

void main(){
    int limit=10;
    char txt[]="This text would be cut, according to limit";
    clrscr();
    for(i; i<strlen(txt); i++){
        if(txt[i] == 32) k=i;
        if(i!=0 && i%limit == 0){
            if(txt[i] != 32) i=k;// This is what bugs the program
            while(j<i) printf("%c",txt[j++]);
            printf("\n");
            }
        }
    getch();
}
```

What my program does:

- It counts variable up to a certain limit through incrementation
- If the current character is a space(ASCII 32), the index of `i` is copied to `k`
- If the index reaches the limit, it initiates the following:

  - If the last character is not a space it sets back `i` to the index of the last space through `k`
  - It will print all characters from the last index used in `j` up to `i`, which by the way is only up to the last space
  - It would create a new line
- Finally, it continues the loop from it's last index `i` which must increment after a loop

Through debugging mode, I found out that after the first line is printed, the `i` remains at the value set by `k` and creates an infinite loop... **I can't really figure out why...**

---

For just those who are asking of what output I expect is that for example, I have the string

```
"This text would be cut, according to limit"
```

This would be limited to ten characters per line but if the last character is not a space, it would just print the unoverflowed words at the first line, then continue doing this until the string ends, the purpose of this, is save time, instead of manually counting the strings then adding `\n` at every limitation

Example Output:

```
This text 
would be 
cut, 
according
 to limit
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the loop counter within the loop?

Comment: Please don't use ASCII values as magic constants. C has `' '` to denote a space.

Comment: What output do you expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code like this:

```
void PrintText(const char txt[])
{
    if (j<i) {
        while(j<i) printf("%c",txt[j++]);
        printf("\n");
        }
}

void PrintText_StripLeft(const char txt[])
{
    for (; (j < i) && (32 == txt[j]); ++j);
    PrintText(txt);
}
```

and in `main`:

```
for(i; i<strlen(txt); i++){
    if(txt[i] == 32) k=i;
    if(i!=0 && (i-j)%limit == 0){
        if(txt[i] != 32 && k){i=k;k=0;}
        PrintText_StripLeft(txt);
        }
    }

PrintText_StripLeft(txt);
```

Changes:

1. `(i-j)%limit` : since you want another `limit` characters
2. `if(txt[i] != 32 && k) {i=k;k=0;}` : you don't want to come back to the same index
3. Last two lines to print the remaining of the string

**EDIT** You must decide what to do with the spaces, your solution (`else ++i` after `i` assignment to `k` doesn't seem to work), so I added two `print` functions: the second one strips the spaces at the beginnig of the line, but you lose characters like this!

Comment: Thanks so much, you even have added about the remaining string that I was about to bother later...

Comment: I added  another validation, `if (j<i)`, to avoid printing empty lines.

Comment: One more thing, why should I use `if(txt[i] != 32 && k)`? I tried removing `&& k` and I got an error.

Comment: the `k` comparison is necessary to avoid coming back to same `k` value: that's why it is reset (`k=0;`) after assignment. This happens for words longuer that the limit, like "automatically".

Comment: Your `else ++i;` solution seems to work without `else`: if we always increment.

Comment: I think the last edit should be displayed it's a much clearer answer for those who would see the problem :)

Comment: So you think the '++i' solution is better? If you didn't discover other problems, then I will publish it.

Comment: The `++i` doesn't work for "automatically" in "This text would be automatically cut, according to limit": it will overcome the limit.

Comment: No, I don't mean it's better, what I mean is that other viewers might expect a simpler solution the earlier edit you have done... It's your answer, and very helpful :)

Comment: Didn't have the time today, so you say it's better to comeback to the previous (the first actually) version? The one that doesn't cut the spaces, I mean

Comment: Just my opinion, it's much simpler answer to the question, But now I understand what your pointing out, it's about the overflowing characters. Sorry for misunderstanding...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you initialize i, j, k?

Comment: No, they are globals.

Comment: Yup, they are globals